# Issue with vertical alignment of links

Tags: html, css

Here is my problem

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 81px;
  background: #669999;
  line-height: 81px;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15%;
  background: green;
}

header nav ul {
  background: yellow;
  width: 650px;
}

header nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 36px;
  background: #006666;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin: auto;
}

header nav li a {
  background: red;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Works</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

I wonder why the `<a>` link are not align **inside** `<li>` list?

The `<a>` link is vertical aligned from header so it's perfect but `<li>` list is above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I vertically center text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-do-i-vertically-center-text-with-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are facing an **inheritance** issue. When defining the `line-height` on the header it will get inherited by the `li` and the `a`. `li` is an `inline-block` element and its height is defined by the fixed height you added *(or by default the height of its content)*

The `a` element is an inline element and its height is defined by its line-height (inherited from the `li`) and logically you will have an overflow since it will be bigger than the height of `li` `(81px > 36px)`. If you remove the fixed height from the `li` its height will be equal to `81px` which is the height of its content `a`.

To avoid this you simply need to remove the inheritance by making the `line-height` of `li` to be `initial` (the `a` will also inherit it) and remove the fixed height:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 81px;
  background: #669999;
  line-height: 81px;
}

header nav {
  background: green;
}

header nav ul {
  background: yellow;
}

header nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 180px;
  line-height: initial;
  background: #006666;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin: auto;
}

header nav li a {
  background: red;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Works</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

In case you want to define a fixed height to `li` simple specify its line height equal to its fixed height:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 81px;
  background: #669999;
  line-height: 81px;
}

header nav {
  background: green;
}

header nav ul {
  background: yellow;
}

header nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 180px;
  height:36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  background: #006666;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin: auto;
}

header nav li a {
  background: red;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Works</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: @Ezabilam I updated with more details and anothe code ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. set     `text-align: center;` to `li`
2. remove the `height` of `li` OR increase it (to `height: 81px;`)

```css
* {
 margin:0;padding:0;
}
header {
 width:100%;
 height:81px;
 background:#669999;
 line-height: 81px;

}
header img {
 margin-left:15%;
 margin-top:20px; /* 50% img-height */
}
header nav {
 float:right;
 margin-right:15%;
 background: green;
}
header nav ul {
 background:yellow;
 width:650px;

}
header nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 180px;
    /* height: 36px; */
    background: #006666;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
header nav li a {
 background:red;
 margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Works</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.
But i want to do a button for each <li> & if i do width;100px (for example), the background of li isn't 100px width but only the text width...

Answer (score 0):

you have the problem of line-height inhereted from the header.

1.remove the height of li or increase it to 65px.

2. To center the inline content of block element like anchor tag you can set the css property text-align: center; to your .

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 81px;
  background: #669999;
  line-height: 81px;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15%;
  background: green;
}

header nav ul {
  background: yellow;
  width: 650px;
  height: 81px;
  text-align: center;   /* center a tag  */
}

header nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 65px;          /* increase the height of li */
  background: #006666;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin: auto;

}

header nav li a {
  background: red;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
                <meta charset ="UTF-8"/>
                <title>Section 2: Javascript Language Basics</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
               
             <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Works</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>   
        </body>
        
        
     </html>
```